# Open .mat files in C

Tags: c, matlab, mat

I'm trying to write a C script able to open .mat files. The .mat files were written in Matlab 2015b 64-bit version. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to compile the code. Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>              /*Std library*/
#include "..\matlablib\mat.h"   /*provided by MathWorks*/

int main(){
  MATFile * pMF;

  printf("Abrindo arquivo .mat...\n"); /*check (1)*/
  pMF = matOpen("teste.mat","r");
  printf("Arquivo .mat aberto.\n");    /*check (2)*/
  getch();
}
```

As I compile this, I get the following message error:

```
matread.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _matOpen
referenced in function _main
matread.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Have anyone had a similar problem before?

Thanks in advance,

Porto

Comment: It sounds like you need to link with the matlab library in order to resolve the external.

Comment: Then I need to configure the VS 2010 installation? Thanks for answering.

Comment: You are very welcome.  I have never used matlab before, but they must provide a library that you can link with.  You'll need to find it, put it in your project, and change your project settings to link with it.

Comment: the function: `getch()` is not in the stdio.h header file,  Suggest `#include` the correct header file (?? conio.h ??)

Comment: when calling the function: `matopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: That's right, there is a missing `header` file. I used the `getch()` function to keep the screen active, as i run the code.